# Open a file and count number of occurrences of '|||'

Tags: python

Im pulling in a file via sftp and having difficulty counting the number of occurrences

```
try:
        with open(os.path.join(args.local, file)) as rcount:
            count= rcount.read().strip().split('|||')
            #count = list(rcount)[-1].rstrip().split('|||')[1]
            logging.info('Number of count: %d' % int(count))
            name = match('([A-Z0-9]+)', file)
```

Neither count statements work.

In the file will be multiple occurrences of
YYYYMMDD|NNNNNNNNXXXXXX|Accepted|||

My logic is to count the number of times [|||] occurs in the file.  I can also read off the word 'accepted'.

Comment: `file.read().count('|||')` ?

Answer (score 1):

As @timgeb has commented, you can use the `count()` method of a string, e.g.:

```
with open(os.path.join(args.local, file)) as rcount:
    count = rcount.read().count("|||")
    logging.info('Number of count: %d' % int(count))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: WARNING   2016-04-25 09:01:50.533: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Apologies that was my error.  That seemed to work but getting unusual results.  Looking further.  Thank you